# Stopping Multiple Instances on Rotate

Tags: android

I have an application that is running and doing some web services in the background.

When I rotate the screen I get a new instance of the application running.  This is not the behavior that I want.

I know that in the onSaveInstanceState I can store a flag in the bundle and then look at the flag in the onCreate to see if a previous instance is running.

But I don't know what to do then to bring my old application in focus; back to the active app.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest for the activity

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

This should ideally take care of it. You can also specify this to be a singleInstance application.